# Type injection in structs

Tags: c++, templates, traits, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I think it is not possible what I am asking, but I wanted to be totally sure, so I ask anyway..

I would like to get a compile time value from a templated struct (usable in constexpr functions) that has been not passed in the template, but injected in some other way.

It is hard to explain, I'll try with some code:

```
template<int A>
struct MagicStruct
{
enum { current = A, injected = /* magic */}
};

template<int A, int B>
struct InjectionStruct
{
enum { first=A, second=B}
/*... injection of B in MagicStruct<A> ... */
};

static const int AVALUE = 1;
static const int BVALUE = 2;

static const int CVALUE = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::first; //== 1
static const int CVALUE = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::second; //== 2
static const int DVALUE = MagicStruct<AVALUE>::injection; //== 2
```

Is there some trick I'm not aware of that would allow that?

[edit] I would like to get DVALUE just with AVALUE in input as template parameter

Comment: Regarding your [edit]: If you have 20 `InjectionStruct`, which one is defining your `MagicStruct` `injected` value?. As explained in my answer, you need to make a relation between `MagicStruct` and which `InjectionStruct` provide the data.

Comment: good point e sophistic question :) it doesn't make too much sense I know.. but I think it should take the one evaluated / declared / defined / whatever as last..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `injected` into a `static int` instead:

```
template<int A>
struct MagicStruct
{
    enum { current = A };
    static int injected;
};

template<int A>
int MagicStruct<A>::injected;
```

Then give `InjectionStruct` a static member whose instantiation will fill in `MagicStruct<A>::injected`:

```
template<int A, int B>
struct InjectionStruct : MagicStruct<A>
{
    enum { first=A, second=B};

    struct filler {
        filler() { MagicStruct<A>::injected = B; }
    };

    static filler inject;
};

template <int A, int B>
typename InjectionStruct<A,B>::filler InjectionStruct<A,B>::inject;
```

Then to carry out the injection, you just need to use `inject` somewhere, or explicitly instantiate it:

```
static const int AVALUE = 1;
static const int BVALUE = 2;

static const int CVALUE = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::first; //== 1
static const int DVALUE = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::second; //== 2
//explicit instantiation
template InjectionStruct<AVALUE,BVALUE>::filler
         InjectionStruct<AVALUE,BVALUE>::inject;
static const int EVALUE = MagicStruct<AVALUE>::injected; //== 2
```

Alternatively, you could hide the instantiation of `injected` in some function which you use to retrieve `first` or `second`.

---

Here's a crazy implementation which relies on injecting the implementation of a function through template instantiation. This might not work on your compiler if it doesn't implement the relevant standards rules correctly, but it's interesting nonetheless, and works completely transparently at compile-time:

```
template<typename>struct Type{};

template<int A>
struct MagicStruct
{
    friend constexpr int get_injected(Type<MagicStruct<A>>);
    static constexpr int current() { return A; }

    template <int V = get_injected(Type<MagicStruct<A>>{})> 
    static constexpr int injected() { return V; } 
};


template<int A, int B>
struct InjectionStruct
{
    static constexpr int first() { return A; }
    static constexpr int second() { return B; }

    friend constexpr int get_injected(Type<MagicStruct<A>>) { return B; }
};
```

Your usage for this implementation is almost exactly as you wanted:

```
static const int AVALUE = 1;
static const int BVALUE = 2;

static const int CVALUE = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::first(); //== 1
static const int DVALUE = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::second(); //== 2
static const int EVALUE = MagicStruct<AVALUE>::injected(); //== 2
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d590a1873a3e4032)

Comment: mate this technique is awesome, I've tried the link you posted before and it seems working. You've remove the f function now, so I'll try it again.. thank you very much!

Comment: Really nice solution, but not sure that is compile time.

Comment: Yes I would like to do some more test.. that static part seems scary ;)

Comment: @TartanLlama  it works also this solution but the first one seems more usable compared to this one.  Do you know if is there a way to encapsulate: template InjectionStruct<AVALUE,BVALUE>::filler
         InjectionStruct<AVALUE,BVALUE>::inject; inside a generic function that returns the first value?

Comment: Nice solution, but injected is not a compile time value. Also be careful with the order of initialisation of the InjectionStructs.

Comment: @OutOfBound I agree. I've tried the first version (link not available now) to test as compile time value and it says that it gives me problems with constexpr functions.  TartanLlama really good attempt anyway :)

Comment: I added a version which works at compile time with no extra code at the use-site.

Comment: this last version is insanely crazy! it totally works at compile time.. real magic

Answer (score 1):

Would the following help you?

```
template<int A, int B>
struct InjectionStruct
{
    constexpr static int first = A;
    constexpr static int second = B;
    constexpr static int MAGIC = B;
};

template<int A, class Injection>
struct MagicStruct
{
    constexpr static int current = A;
    constexpr static auto injected = Injection::MAGIC;
};
static const int AVALUE = 1;
static const int BVALUE = 2;

static const int CVALUE = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::first; //== 1
static const int CVALUE = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::second; //== 2
static const int DVALUE = MagicStruct<AVALUE, InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>>::injected; //== 2
```

It's hard to give more in depth advice, without knowing what you want to inject.

Comment: Thank you too :)  please check my edited post. In my case I want to get  DVALUE  by only using AVALUE. I don't know BVALUE when I use the MagicStruct

Answer (score 1):

You will need some relation between the `InjectionStruct` and `MagicStruct`. For this reason, I included an additional template parameter for the `injected` value and a `typdef` in the `InjectionStruct`.

The first example use the `InjectionStruct` itself to define the specific MagicStruct:

Example:

```
// MagicStruct is generic
template<int A, int INJ>
struct MagicStruct
{
    enum { current = A, injected = INJ};

};

// Injection struct has it own copy of MagicStruct
template<int A, int B>
struct InjectionStruct
{
    enum { first=A, second=B};

    // Provide custom magic number
    constexpr static int provideInjection(){ return B;}

    // Own copy of magicStruct, injected by this template instance.
    template <int X> struct MagicStruct: public ::MagicStruct<X,provideInjection()>{};
};

constexpr static const int AVALUE = 1;
constexpr static const int BVALUE = 2;

constexpr static const int CVALUE1 = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::first; //== 1
constexpr static const int CVALUE2 = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::second; //== 2
// Using a specific InjectionStruct, provies the MagicStruct with one argument.
constexpr static const int DVALUE3 = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::MagicStruct<AVALUE>::injected; //== 2


int main()
{
    std::cout << CVALUE1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << CVALUE2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << DVALUE3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the following solution, `MagicStruct` take it magic value from a default `InjectionStruct` which is fix.

```
// InjectionStruct is generic.
template<int A, int B>
struct InjectionStruct
{
    enum { first=A, second=B};
    constexpr static int provideInjection(){ return A+B;}
};


constexpr static const int AVALUE = 1;
constexpr static const int BVALUE = 2;

// Define MagicStruct based on a specific InjectionStruct
template<int A, int INJ = InjectionStruct<A,BVALUE>::provideInjection()>
struct MagicStruct
{
    enum { current = A, injected = INJ};
};

constexpr static const int CVALUE1 = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::first; //== 1
constexpr static const int CVALUE2 = InjectionStruct<AVALUE, BVALUE>::second; //== 2
constexpr static const int DVALUE1 = MagicStruct<3>::injected; // == 5
constexpr static const int DVALUE2 = MagicStruct<DVALUE1>::injected; // == 7
constexpr static const int DVALUE3 = MagicStruct<DVALUE2>::injected; // == 9


int main(int n, char* args[])
{
    std::cout << CVALUE1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << CVALUE2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << DVALUE1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << DVALUE2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << DVALUE3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt :)  check my edited post. In my case I want to get  DVALUE  by only using AVALUE.

Comment: DVALUE is essentially an alias for BVALUE so it will always be dependent on BVALUE. I think what you want is, that the compiler looks at all definitions of InjectionStruct and choose the right one depending on AVALUE. That behaviour is not possible, abd even if it would be, you would not want to do it, since it is not one-to-one mapping.
I am sorry to say that, but you should think about a different design.

Comment: I am just experimenting here so no design problem. I just want a way to get a compile time value in template<int A> MagicStruct, that has been inserted not with that template value.

Comment: Thank you :) yes the second one works. Unfortunately it is not generic enough for what I was thinking of.. you have to define struct MagicStruct every time. Good solution anyway

Comment: @user3770392: explain "You have to define struct MagicStruct every time" please.

Comment: @AdrianMaire suppose you have 100 integers value, you would need: constexpr static const int YOURVALUE1 = .... /* repeat 100 times*/ and same for:  template<int A, int INJ = InjectionStruct<YOURVALUE1,YOURVALUE2>::provideInjection()>
struct MagicStruct
{
    enum { current = A, injected = INJ};
};

Comment: @user3770392: Ok, edited to make the "different" usage apparent.

Comment: Yes now it's better :)  still not totally generic yet though, BVALUE is fixed in this example. Is a very interesting technique though

Comment: @user3770392: Well, you may put BVALUE as a template parameter too. What you cannot have is BVALUE fixed but flexible at the same time: either you provide it, either it's fix.